# cvWaitkey for for increasing values

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a program written in c++ with opencv which should calculate a disparity map. Now I want to play around with the values wihin a while loop looking like this:

```
while(true) {

  cv::StereoSGBM disparity(minDISP,numDISP,SADWindowSize, disparitySmoothness1, disparitySmoothness2);
  cv::Mat disparityMap, disparityNorm;

  disparity(undistortedLeft[1], undistortedRight[1], disparityMap);
  disparityMap*=(1/16.0);
  cv::normalize(disparityMap, disparityNorm, 0,255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);
  cv::imshow("disparityMap", disparityNorm);
  key = cv::waitKey(0);

  switch(char(key)) {
    case 'n': numDISP+=16;
    case 'm': minDISP+=1;
    case 's': SADWindowSize+=2;
    case 'q': break;
  }
}
```

key is declared as `char key;`

the problem I have now is the following.
If I press `n` everything is working well, if I press `m` the program increases `n` and `s` as well. The same if I press `s`. If I press `q` nothing is happening.

I also tried it using if else statements and it was the same result.
Is this because of `key` saves the buttons pressed before in any way?

Maybe someone of you can help me with this.

Comment: okay if I use this nothing is working anymore. The thing ist that I can print the values using `std::cout << key; ` which displays the exact char value (exept keys like esc or shift)

Comment: Wait, are you wanting a key press of 'q' to break you out of the while loop? Because it will only break you out of the switch statement.

Comment: in a switch case it will go on to the next code part until it finds a `break`. so you should add a `break;` after `numDISP+=16;` `minDISP+=1;` and `SADWindowSize+=2;` if you dont want them to be executed when one of the previous keys is pressed... the `break` will bring you only out of the switch statement, not out of the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a trouble with the syntax of switch-case. Did you leave intentionally break statement in the end of each case?

```
switch(char(key)) 
{
    case 'n': 
        numDISP+=16;
        break;
    case 'm': 
        minDISP+=1;
        break;
    case 's': 
        SADWindowSize+=2;
        break;
    case 'q': 
        // do nothing
        break;
  }
```

Comment: on case q I think he wants to return out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

to work on all systems you have not only use break statement but also to do this:

```
int key;
key = waitKey() & 255;
```

Note that I am not using waitKey(0) since it gives 0 ms to draw your image. In practice waitKey will take time to draw it still.